# Access denied for user `user`@`localhost` (using password: YES) while connecting custom TCP port in AWS

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-ec2, websocket, phpwebsocket

I am trying to create a *Websocket* Server in *PHP*. I use a **custom port** for *Websocket*. The socket functions are working properly, but I am unable to access **MySql** from there. I can access MySql from the defaults ports (80 and 443) and didn't find any issue in the website hosted in the same server.

I get the following error while connecting to MySql :

`Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`

The host-name, username, password and database name are correct. Can anyone help me fix this?

Thanks.